# Building a java project with gradle to integrate into Android Studio project

Tags: java, android, gradle, spotify

I'm trying to build a jar file out of the Spotify (Java) web api wrapper to then integrate the wrapper as a module in my android studio project.

The java project I'm trying to build is here: 
 https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-java

My build.gradle file is like this so far:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories{
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies{
    compile "com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.5.0"
    compile "net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:2.4:jdk15"
    compile "com.google.guava:guava:18.0"
    compile "commons-codec:commons-codec:1.5"
    compile "commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:2.0.2"

    compile "org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.commons-httpclient:2.0.2_1"


    compile "org.apache.geronimo.bundles:commons-httpclient:3.1_2"
    compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.5"
    compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.5"
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5'
 }
```

When I try to run gradle build I am getting the folowing errors:

```
Error:(46, 52) cannot find symbol variable BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY
Error:(46, 11) cannot find symbol method getParams()
Error:(47, 11) cannot find symbol method getParams()

Error:(69, 13) cannot find symbol method setRequestEntity(org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.StringRequestEntity)

Error:(74, 52) cannot find symbol variable BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY
Error:(74, 11) cannot find symbol method getParams()
Error:(75, 11) cannot find symbol method getParams()
```

Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':wrapper:compileReleaseJava'.
Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Information:
BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 4.266 secs
Information:8 errors
Information:30 warnings
```

The full console output is here:

http://pastebin.com/vDeEzi8A

How can I solve the missing symbol problem ? I tried adding directly the jar files of http-client in the dependencies like this:

```
compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.5.jar')
compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3.5.jar')
compile files('libs/httpclient-cache-4.3.5.jar')
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.5.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.6.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar')
compile files('libs/fluent-hc-4.3.5.jar')
```

but it did not work either. What I intend to do is get the generated jar file and then add it to my Android Studio project and be able to use the wrapper. Also would this be way the correct way to add a wrapper to an android project?
Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you have a look at the [Android SDK](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-android-sdk/)? It's still in Beta, but it'd offer you important features such as playback of full songs, which the Web API doesn't.

Comment: @michealt Yes, I did have a look. However I wanted to use the web-api for the things such as playlist management that the SDK doesn't support yet. So I found the wrapper to be a good option.

Comment: @Sergex, not sure why you need all these libraries, but it looks that the library from the wrappers pom.xml (`https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-java/blob/master/pom.xml`) is missing commons-httpclient v.3.1

Comment: It's been added since and is now available through Maven Central.